# Relationship between RKObjectMapping and RKEntityMapping

Tags: ios, json, core-data, restkit-0.20

Say I have `JSON` like this:

```
{
    "hits": 4056,
    "books": [
        {
            "name": "Book 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Book 2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Book 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to map this response to `BooksResponse` object:

```
@interface BooksResponse
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger hits;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray* books;
@end
```

Where books property is an array of `CoreData` Book objects. I'm using `RKObjectEntity` to map `BooksResponse` like this:

```
RKObjectMapping* booksResponseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[BooksResponse class]];
[booksResponseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"hits" : @"hits"
}];

[booksResponseMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping
        relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"books"
                             toKeyPath:@"books"
                           withMapping:[self booksMapping]]];
```

And booksMapping is implemented like this:

```
RKEntityMapping* bookMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Book"
                                                       inManagedObjectStore:[self managedObjectStore]];
[bookMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
        @"name" : @"name"
}];
```

but whenever `RestKit` tries to perform mapping there is a crash:

```
CoreData: error: Failed to call designated initializer on NSManagedObject class 'Book'
```

I checked, during execution `ManagedObjectStore` exists on `RKObjectManager` instance. Application hangs in class `RKMappingOperation:355` on line

```
id currentValue = [self.destinationObject valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
```

Is there a way one can make relationship between plain objectiveC object and `NSManagedObject` so that only part of `JSON` response is persisted in `CoreData`?

Comment: What request are you making? I guess the managed object store is not being made available to the mapping.

Comment: It is simple http GET request. All other entity mappings, which don't have relationship between simple ObjC class and CoreData class, work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the difference between `RKObjectRequestOperation` and `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation`. Because you only have 1 response descriptor and it matches an object (not a managed object), RestKit will use `RKObjectRequestOperation`. When it does this, the managed object store is not available during the mapping so no managed objects can be created.

A workaround:

Instead of using 1 response descriptor, use 2. The first just creates the `BooksResponse` and maps the `hits`. The second creates the `Book`s and maps the `name`.

Once the operation is complete, you will be provided with a mapping response whose dictionary contains 2 keys: null and "books". The null key holds the `BooksResponse` instance and the "books" key holds the `Book` instances. You can now update the `BooksResponse` instance to populate the relationship.

Note, the keys in the mapping response correspond to the key paths specified on the 2 response descriptors.